# Insert innerHTML of all elements which have same class name to another elements multiple

Tags: javascript, html

I have some elements have same class name and i insert their innerHTML in another element have classname "show". Expected output

```
<p class="show">
  <i>1</i>
  <i>2</i>
  <i>3</i>
  <i>4</i>
  <i>5</i>
</p>
```

Here is my code snippet;

```js
var source = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("source"))
var show = document.getElementsByClassName("show")[0];

show.innerHTML = source.reduce((a, el) => a += el.textContent, '')
```

```css
.show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<span class="source">1</span>
<span class="source">2</span>
<span class="source">3</span>
<span class="source">4</span>
<span class="source">5</span>

<p class="show"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance like this:

```
var source = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("source"));
var show = document.getElementById("show");
show.innerHTML = source.reduce((a, el) =>  a += '<p>' + el.innerHTML + '</p>', '');
```

P.S I'm getting source element by id, as it is singular, no sense to get it by class.

```
<p id="show"></p>
```

https://jsbin.com/hoxagih/4/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: i don't want copy original codes, i just want it insert some element, it should be p tag or etc.

Comment: JSFiddle shows expected output? Or something wrong?

Comment: it's copy original codes with class name. i updated my expected output please check question.

Comment: Fixed, check pls.

Comment: Thats exactly what i want and it keeps my code contructre,thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

I'd select all the `span`s, then insert them into the `show` with `appendChild`:

```js
const show = document.querySelector('.show');
document.querySelectorAll('.source')
  .forEach(span => show.appendChild(span));
console.log(show.innerHTML);
```

```css
.show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<span class="source">1</span>
<span class="source">2</span>
<span class="source">3</span>
<span class="source">4</span>
<span class="source">5</span>

<p class="show"></p>
```

If you also want to remove the class names, then do that when appending:

```js
const show = document.querySelector('.show');
document.querySelectorAll('.source')
  .forEach(span => {
    show.className = '';
    show.appendChild(span)
  });
console.log(show.innerHTML);
```

```css
.show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<span class="source">1</span>
<span class="source">2</span>
<span class="source">3</span>
<span class="source">4</span>
<span class="source">5</span>

<p class="show"></p>
```

If you want to change the tag name as well, then extract the `textContent` of the original element, append the new element, and remove the old element:

```js
const show = document.querySelector('.show');
document.querySelectorAll('.source')
  .forEach(span => {
    const i = show.appendChild(document.createElement('i'));
    i.textContent = span.textContent;
    span.remove();
  });
console.log(show.innerHTML);
```

```css
.show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<span class="source">1</span>
<span class="source">2</span>
<span class="source">3</span>
<span class="source">4</span>
<span class="source">5</span>

<p class="show"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not what i want exactly. I upadate question, please check. I want copy to textContent and insert it multiple tag(it should be p, i, span or something else)

Comment: See edit, create the element of the tag name you want, and set its `textContent` to the same as the `.source` you're iterating over

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution:

```
var source = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("source"));
for(i=0;i<source.length;i++){
var x=document.querySelector(".show");
var element=document.createElement("i");
element.innerHTML=source[i].innerHTML;
x.appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: thank u too, for loop give me idea for main problem.